# Exception could not catch from calllbacked function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling a login function using firebase authentication and checking the custom user claim. If not, then throw the exception. I could not catch the exception in caller function. May I know why?

```
const handleLogin = async (data) => {
console.log(data);
setIsSubmitting(true);
auth
  .login(data.email, data.password)
  .then((res) => {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
    const message = auth.mapAuthCodeToMessage(error.code);
    setLoginError(message ?? error.message);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    mounted.current && setIsSubmitting(false);
  });
};
```

firebase authentication

```
async function login(email, password) {
return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(
  async function (res) {
    const currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;
    if (currentUser) {
      currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(async function (idTokenResult) {
        if (idTokenResult.claims.role == "ADMIN") {
          await signIn(idTokenResult.token);
        } else {
          throw new Error("You role is not authorised!");
        }
      });
    }
  }
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not returning the promise here:

```
async function login(email, password) {
return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(
  async function (res) {
    const currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;
    if (currentUser) {
      currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then(async function (idTokenResult) { // ***
        if (idTokenResult.claims.role == "ADMIN") {                        // ***
          await signIn(idTokenResult.token);                               // ***
        } else {                                                           // ***
          throw new Error("You role is not authorised!");                  // ***
        }                                                                  // ***
      });                                                                  // ***
    }
  }
);
}
```

You need to return that promise for the caller to know about the rejection.

But there's a more fundamental issue: You're not making any use of the fact you're using [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions. There's no point to an `async` function that doesn't have any `await` in it. In general, don't mix [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) functions with explicit promise callbacks, it's much too easy to make mistakes like not returning the promise. Instead, use `await`.

Here's a translation of those functions using `await` (**note**: it may not be perfect, it's meant to guide you in the right direction, but naturally I can't run it nor do I know your context, so adjust as necessary):

```
const handleLogin = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    try {
        await auth.login(data.email, data.password);
        navigate(from, { replace: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        const message = auth.mapAuthCodeToMessage(error.code);
        setLoginError(message ?? error.message);
    } finally {
        if (mounted.current) {
            setIsSubmitting(false);
        }
    }
};

async function login(email, password) {
    const res = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    const currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;
    if (currentUser) {
        const idTokenResult = await currentUser.getIdTokenResult();
        if (idTokenResult.claims.role == "ADMIN") {
            await signIn(idTokenResult.token);
        } else {
            throw new Error("You role is not authorised!");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. Yes, I put the return in front of currentUser.getIdTokenResult function, can catch the exception. You are right, there is no need for promise callbacks. It is working now.